# ¿Como obtener los datos de un json?

Tags: php, laravel, postman

Necesito extraer los datos de este `json` que envío mediante `Postman`

```
{
    "json":[
        {
            "email": "18",
            "name": "Laravel",
            "surname": "18",
            "role": "Laravel",
            "password": "18"
        }
    ]
}
```

y así lo recibo en `laravel`

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $json=$request->input('json',null);

    $params=json_decode($json,true);
}
```

Pero me da este error y no se porque

> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in file

Comment: Es que el valor del campo`json` es efectivamente un `array`. Si intentas con `json_decode($json[0], null);` funcionaría. Saludos

Comment: Pero ya que estás trabajando con Laravel, ¿no sería mejor leer el JSON haciendo uso de las posibilidades que ofrece ese framework? Por ejemplo ellos dicen en el apartado *Retrieving JSON Input Values* de la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests) que puedes usar la notación con punto para obtener valores de un determinado objeto dentro de un array. Lo que pasa es que no entiendo por qué tu objeto se llama `json` en genérico y no tiene el nombre de ninguna entidad como `usuario, empleado, cliente` etc. Ya en `$json` deberías tener el objeto y si quieres leer alguna propiedad...

Comment: ...debería ser algo así:, para el email `$email = $request->input('json.email);` o para el nombre: `$name = $request->input('json.name);`, etc.

Comment: La variable $json ya debiera contener el array sin que necesites hacer json_decode, dado que postman lo haya enviado con content-type application/json